# Are google drive folders visible to people without a link but fully accessible to people with a link?

Tags: google-drive

I have a google drive folder that I do not want visible to some clients. I have to keep it fully accessible to people with a link for the purposes of a webform sending data to a google sheet in folder.

So the folder and its contents are fully visible to anyone with a link. If someone does not have a link to the folder, will it even appear to them in google drive?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I'm unsure how I can possibly be more specific? I set a folder to accessible  to anyone with a link. If a person does not have the link do they have the ability to see that a folder even exists or will it just not appear for them?

Comment: Why not test that yourself? Clear cookies, and try to view the document without logging in or password.